# i am trying to build a registration form by Django using forms.py

Tags: python, django

here Every time i enter any data nothing happen except that the page is reloaded and password and verify password are empty even if i didn't write them typically the same the raise.ValidationError is not displayed any advice ?

Views.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from shoghlanah.forms import SignUpForm
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from django.contrib.auth import logout
    from shoghlanah.models import *



    def EmployerRegistration(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],password= form.cleaned_data['password'],first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'],address=form.cleaned_data['address'],mobile=form.cleaned_data['mobile'])
                user.save()
                employer =Employer(user=user,first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'],address=form.cleaned_data['address'],mobile=form.cleaned_data['mobile'])
                employer.save()
                #Employer=user.get_profile()
                #Employer.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                #Employer.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                #Employer.address=form.cleaned_data['address']
                #Employer.mobile =form.cleaned_data['mobile']
                #Employer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') 

            #else:
             #    return render_to_response('Sign_up_Employer.html',{'form':form},context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        else:
        #user is not submitting show them the registeration form
                form= SignUpForm()
                context = {'form':form}
                return render_to_response('Sign_up_Employer.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from shoghlanah.models import *


class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    username      = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    first_name    = forms.CharField(label=(u'First name'))
    last_name     = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last name'))
    address       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Address'))
    email         = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
    password      = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'),widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password1     = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'),widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    mobile        = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Mobile'))

    class Meta:
        model = Employer

        exclude =('user',)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username

            raise forms.ValidationError("That username  already exists. Please select another")




    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
              raise forms.ValidationError("not matched")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

sign_up_Employer.html

```
{%block content%}
<form action ="" method ="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if form.errors %}<p>Please Correct </p> {% endif %}
<div class ="register_div">
{%if form.username.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.username.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="username"{% if form.username.errors %} class= "error"{% endif %}> Username</label></p>
<p>{{form.username}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.first_name.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.first_name.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="first_name"{% if form.first_name.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>First name</label></p>
<p>{{form.first_name}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.last_name.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.last_name.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="last_name"{% if form.last_name.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Last name</label></p>
<p>{{form.last_name}}</p>
 </div>
<div class ="register_div">
{%if form.address.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.address.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="address"{% if form.address.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Address'</label></p>
<p>{{form.address}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.email.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.email.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="email"{% if form.email.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Email Address</label></p>
<p>{{form.email}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.password.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.password.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="password"{% if form.password.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Password</label></p>
<p>{{form.password}}</p>
 </div>

 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.password1.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.password1.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="password1"{% if form.password1.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Verify Password</label></p>
<p>{{form.password1}}</p>
 </div>

 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.mobile.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.mobile.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="mobile"{% if form.mobile.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Mobile</label></p>
<p>{{form.mobile}}</p>
 </div>
 <p><input type =submit alt =register></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Employer(models.Model):#Employer inherits from User
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    employer_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePictureDB', null=False , blank=False) 
    #profile pictures will be uploaded to ProfilePictureDB 
    hidden_values = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    #hidden_values will contain all the attributes that the employer/contractor wants to hide
    signature = models.OneToOneField(Signature)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: *You* are telling to redirect to login if the form is invalid (no data). You should redirect to the registration form and show the error if the form is invalid. if form.is_valid(): ... else: ...

Comment: i am sry but how come "return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')" is after  checking if form.is_valid(): and saving the employer in the database or i am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":

    if form.is_valid():
        # ....
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  # not indented
```

The return is unindented out of the is_valid() block.  So, a POST, regardless of the form's validity, will redirect.  Change to

```
if request.method == "POST":

    if form.is_valid():
        # ....
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  # indented
```

Update:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username

        raise forms.ValidationError("That username  already exists. Please select another")
```

This is wrong; you can't raise after you return.  The raise should go in the try block.

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username)
        raise forms.ValidationError("That username already exists. "
                                    "Please select another")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username
```

Comment: @Mai Zuhair this is what I was trying to explain. Sorry I didn't make myself clear

Comment: i am sorry but why it keeps on asking me to rewrite the password and the verify one??

Comment: and if i didn't write password and verify password typically the same it didn't display the forms.ValidationError message and just reload the page with empty passwords fields any help please ?

Comment: you might need to add another question with things broken up a bit.  There are multiple errors going on here.

Comment: could you please specify what type of errors and where are they ?

Comment: ive written this Question as i couldnot update my database 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233832/cant-add-a-user-to-the-database