# Can't add a User to the Database

Tags: python, django

when ever i fill the form and submit nothing is added to the database instead it  reloads the page with empty passwords field and even if the form contains password not equal  to Verifypassword ValidationError doesnot appear ....thank u

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    username      = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    first_name    = forms.CharField(label=(u'First name'))
    last_name     = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last name'))
    address       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Address'))
    email         = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
    password      = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'),widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password1     = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'),widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    mobile        = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Mobile'))

    class Meta:
        model = Employer
        ## check whats Exclude !!!!
        exclude = ('user',)

def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username

            raise forms.ValidationError("That username  already exists. Please select another")

def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("not matched")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

view.py

```
def EmployerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            employer =Employer.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data["username"],password= form.cleaned_data['password'],first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'],address=form.cleaned_data['address'],mobile=form.cleaned_data['mobile'])
            employer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  



        else:
                return render_to_response('Sign_up_Employer.html',{'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


    else:
    #user is not submitting show them the registeration form
            form= SignUpForm()
            context = {'form':form}
            return render_to_response('Sign_up_Employer.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Sign_Up_Employer.html

```
{%block content%}
<form action ="" method ="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if form.errors %}<p>Please Correct </p> {% endif %}
<div class ="register_div">
{%if form.username.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.username.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="username"{% if form.username.errors %} class= "error"{% endif %}> Username</label></p>
<p>{{form.username}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.first_name.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.first_name.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="first_name"{% if form.first_name.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>First name</label></p>
<p>{{form.first_name}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.last_name.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.last_name.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="last_name"{% if form.last_name.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Last name</label></p>
<p>{{form.last_name}}</p>
 </div>
<div class ="register_div">
{%if form.address.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.address.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="address"{% if form.address.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Address'</label></p>
<p>{{form.address}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.email.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.email.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="email"{% if form.email.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Email Address</label></p>
<p>{{form.email}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.password.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.password.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="password"{% if form.password.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Password</label></p>
<p>{{form.password}}</p>
 </div>

 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.password1.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.password1.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="password1"{% if form.password1.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Verify Password</label></p>
<p>{{form.password1}}</p>
 </div>

 <div class ="register_div">
{%if form.mobile.errors%}<p class= "error">{{form.mobile.errors}}</p>{% endif %}
 <p> <label for ="mobile"{% if form.mobile.errors %} class= "error"{%endif%}>Mobile</label></p>
<p>{{form.mobile}}</p>
 </div>
 <p><input type =submit alt =register></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you're ignoring the whole point of modelforms by (a) defining all your fields explicitly and (b) creating the object manually from cleaned_data rather than just doing `form.save()`.

Comment: can we see the html template?

Comment: i have added the html template

Comment: I think you should start with a Python tutorial, then the Django tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if this is just a cut-and-paste problem (although since it was the same in your other (deleted) question, I'm inclined to think not), but the indentation for your two `clean` methods is wrong. They're not currently part of the ModelForm class at all, so will not be called. Indent them one level, so they are at the same level as `class Meta`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that in HTML template you are not setting the `method` attribute of form to `POST`  e.g.

```
<form method="post">
```